# Disable page transition on a page

Tags: flutter, dart

I use a pageTransitionTheme on the main.dart file and I use a Hero animation too on a page. The problem is when I click on the picture the Hero animation and the CupertinoPageTransition are work at the same time. Is there any solution to disable CuperinoPageTransition in this situation without removing it from main.dart file?

Thanks!

main.dart

```
...
pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
        TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      }),

...
```

detail_screen.dart

```
...
ImageSlideshow(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 200,
  initialPage: 0,
  indicatorColor: cSecondaryColor,
  indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
  children: [
     for (var image in images!['imageUrls'])
       InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ImageViewScreen.routeName,
              arguments: image,
            );
          },
          child: Hero(
            tag: '$image',
            child: Image.network(
               image.toString(),
               fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
           ),
         ),
       ),
      ],
    ),
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `pageTransitionsTheme` argument

You can use `onGenerateRoute` to customise the behaviour when a new Route is generated like so

```
onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
  if (settings.name == "/someRoute") {
// See other customisable parameters of this class like transitionBuilder
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      settings: settings, 
      pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => SomePage(),
      transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0)
    );
  }
  // Unknown route
  //You can use any route that you like here or make a new route by inheriting the other routes

  return CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (_) => UnknownPage());
},
```

The `CupertinoPageRoute` will use the `CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder` transitionbuilder class by default